# Helm upgrade and immediately show logs

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Is there a way to do

```
helm upgrade something .
```

And immediately attach to created container logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not.

For some idea of the complexity involved, consider upgrading this Deployment:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  replicas: 10
  template:
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: wait
          image: busybox
          command: [sleep, '60']
      containers: [...]
```

In order to do this, you'd need to know what Deployments were being created (which data Helm has); but then track through to their managed ReplicaSets and Pods, attach to each one as it's created and read its logs.  With this particular artificial Deployment, the `sleep` needs to complete before a Pod will become ready, which needs to happen before one of the old Pods is deleted.  That means your log-watcher tool will be waiting for a minimum of 9 minutes for all of the Pods to be created on an upgrade.

(There's no reason such a tool couldn't be written, but it's not part of the standard `helm` or `kubectl` command set.)

In my practical experience it does take observably long for a Pod to start up.  If I `helm upgrade something .` and then immediately run `kubectl get pods`, even with a single replica it can routinely be 10-15 seconds before only the new pod is running.

If you're dealing with a small number of Pods (I might want to do this in a developer cluster, for example, with only a single replica, and less than 100% confidence my Pod will actually start) a workaround can be to wait for the pod to exist, then look at its logs.

```bash
# upgrade the release
helm upgrade something .

# watch the list of pods; you will see the new pod created
# and (hopefully) the old one destroyed
kubectl get pod -w

# now get the logs for the (hopefully one) running pod for
# the deployment
kubectl logs deployment/something-server
```

The `kubectl logs deployment/name` trick only really works reliably if you have just one replica and it did start up successfully.  You will need to use the longer `kubectl logs something-server-12345678-abcde` knowing the full Pod name if the startup isn't successful.